# Assign material breaks viewport

Tags: materials, 3d-view

Whenever I try to assign multiple materials to a mesh the view port displays the mesh as a mess of black faces. This happens on all the models I've tried. It does not effect cycles rendering but it shows this way in LookDev and makes it very difficult to work.
[image: Before assigning]

[image: After]

[image: Object mode]